# Android: Find the first occurrance of a char in a TextView or Editable

Tags: android, string, textview, indexof

I'm using a multiline TextView to display scrolling data that comes in via USB. Eventually the amount of data in the TextView backing buffer is so large that things slow down, so I need to remove the start of the buffer as I append new data to the end. I have this working with TextView.getEditableText().delete() but it would be nice to delete up to and including the next newline (\n) character so I don't leave partial lines at the top, which look weird if the user scrolls down to examine past data.

I have that working via Editable.toString().indexOf(), but it seems inefficient to create and initialize an intermediate String object just so I can look for the first occurrance of a char value. However, I haven't found the equivalent of indexOf() associated with Editable.

Any ideas on how to efficiently obtain the offset of the first occurrance of a character in a TextView (or Editable) ***without*** first converting to a String?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no other way of achieving that. You can at most set that intermediate String as a `WeakReference` or `SoftReference`, so it'll be soon collected by the Garbage Collector, but I don't see other way...

Comment: Another approach I considered was an int[] in which I store the offsets of newlines. But those offset values would be constantly changing as the front of the backing buffer was deleted, something of a maintenance nightmare. I might code it up just to measure performance.

Comment: Try if you want, but I don't know how much is worth complicating as much the code instead of doing a simple `for` loop like this:       

cutpoint = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_newlines_to_count; i++)
   cutpoint = text.indexOf("\n", (cutpoint < 0)? 0 : cutpoint + 1);

Comment: Yes, but then you are recreating and rescanning the String object every single time. My thought was that since you already have the data when you insert each line, storing it then would save all of that constant recalc. However, as I noted you'd have to update the int[] with every delete operation. That's better than constantly rescanning a String but still may not be worth it.

Comment: You're right, but if you want to truncate just the first `\n` or the second at most, it wouldn't be a big mess. If you finally use the `int[]` way, I think it's not necessary to reiterate again the whole array, simply substract to each position the length of the string you just truncated (this would need that length, though). However, even using the approach I suggested (and sometimes I need to add 5 lines/second to a `TextView`), I have never had any performance issue, I wonder why you might have.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "constant recalc". You'd have to scan the array, adjusting each int by the amount deleted from the front of the backing buffer. Still might not be too bad, though.